# CQL selecting rows without columns

Tags: cassandra, thrift, cql3, cqlsh

After creating a table in CQL3:

```
CREATE TABLE data(
 row_key text,
 k1 text,
 k2 text,
 PRIMARY KEY (row_key , k1 ,k2 )
);
```

I would like to know all of the cassandra rows stored in that table. but when I run this in cqlsh:

```
SELECT row_key  FROM data;
```

I get back many duplicate entries. I basically get an entry for **every column** that I inserted. Meaning: I get an entry for row_key for every ( k1 & k2).

But my original intent was: "Give me a list of all the partition (row) keys". I do not want to serialize all of the columns (k1 & k2) too.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have currently hot fixed this by using "LIMIT 1" in my SELECT query. It still serializes one column, but not the entire row. This is better than nothing.

Comment: yes this is the way to go. How could i miss this :/ In fact i am using limit queries to retrieve top 5 locations for a user in my case.

Answer (score 2):

This is how CQL3 represents the data internally. it makes partitions for columns. You need to understand the storage model of CQL3. There are very good reads regarding this on DataStax blog. Have a look at these :

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-for-cassandra-experts

Edit :
      here we are dealing with CQL3 not thrift. if you read the second link in my answer (cql3-for-cassandra-experts) you will understand how data is stored in the storage engine when a table is created using CQL3. say we have created the following table :

```
    CREATE TABLE song_tags (
      id uuid,
      tag_name text,
      PRIMARY KEY (id, tag_name)
    );
```

and say we have following rows as represented by a single storage engine :

```
    f665cfc469eb |    blues  | 1973 

    f665cfc469ea |    covers | 2003
```

These are stored by CQL3 as follows :

```
    |id             |    tag_name |
     -----------------------------
    |f665cfc469eb        blues    |
    |f665cfc469eb   |    1973     |
    |                             |
    |f665cfc469ea        covers   |
    |f665cfc469ea   |    2003     |
```

Now if you do a SELECT * FROM song_tags; this is going to be the output:

```
    id                                   | column1 | value
    --------------------------------------+---------+-------
    8a172618-b121-4136-bb10-f665cfc469ea |    2003 |
    8a172618-b121-4136-bb10-f665cfc469ea |  covers |
    a3e64f8f-bd44-4f28-b8d9-f665cfc469eb |    1973 |
    a3e64f8f-bd44-4f28-b8d9-f665cfc469eb |   blues |
```

**P.S to achieve what you want; you could try using sets and maps. they might solve your problem.**

Comment: The first key is a partition key. In the storage engine, the partition key is used for cassandra storage rows (not CQL rows). As such, if I only query the partition key, there is no reason to start serializing the columns (which contain the clustering keys). Can I change something in my CQL query or my CREATE TABLE definitions so that it doesn't do that?

Comment: k1 and k2 are part of the primary key. cassandra will create a new entry every time you have a new value for any of the variables in the primary key. you can verify this using SELECT * in your query.

Comment: If I understand correctly thrift maps my schema into data[row_key][k1,k2]. Where the **values** of k1 & k2 are stored compositely as  **column names** (each k1,k2 pair as a single column name) . How should I change my schema or query to reflect the question: "Give me all values of row_key" without getting each entry multiple times? Should I declare row_key differently?

Comment: Your example `CREAT TABLE` has 2 columns but your example data has 3.

Comment: sorry i should have made it more clear. i have edited it. That example data is what a single storage engine or the old cli schema would represent.

Comment: @Train Of Thought, thank you for your in-depth attention and detailed answer. However, from your link: see http://www.datastax.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/rdiagram5.png . The partition key (id) is mapped as a row in the storage engine. My problem is that I want to select the partition key, without reading the potential 2GB of column data stored under it. Is there anything I can do besides switching to CLI? I don't think I can use sets, as they are limitted to 2 Giga items (1 row on a single machine) They do however look very interesting.